# understanding YUM update error... requires, removing, updated by

Tags: yum

RHEL 7.6,  managing an offline system with the updates from an identical online system.  I have a local repository created on the offline system and doing a `yum update` has worked fine... until.

```
.
.
.
Found and removing 0 unneeded dependencies

Error: Package: libkadm5-1.15.1.1-34.el7.x86_64 (@dvd)
    Requires: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-34.el7
    Removing: krb5-libs-1.15.1-34.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.6)
       krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-34.el7
    Updated by: krb5-libs-1.15.1-37.el7_6.x86_64 (local)
       krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-37.el7_6
```

I also get the same error...

- regarding krb5-devel-1.15.1-37.el7_6.x86_64
- requires 1.15.1-34.el7
- removing 1.15.1-34.el7
- updated by 1.15.1-37.el7_6

And for `openssl-devel` but with different version numbers.  What I do not understand is how this could have come about where anything done on this offline system has been done successfully on the online system.  So why this problem with versions, and how can it be corrected?

Answer (score 3):

You have a package, `libkadm5`, that requires a specific version of `krb5-libs` (`krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-34.el7`).

You are running an update process that would like to update `krb5-libs` to version `1.15.1-37.el7_6`, but that would break the package `libkadm5` due to no longer having the exact version of `krb5-libs` it wants.  The update was not performed as it could not resolve that dependency conflict.

The proper resolution would be to make sure you have `libkadm5-1.15.1-37.el7_6` available in your YUM repositories (should be located in the `updates` repository of EL 7.6).  That should allow the `krb5-libs` package to update cleanly.

As to why this happened, I am not certain but it may have to with the versioning of the package in question.  Looking closer at the package you are having an issue with, `libkadm5-1.15.1.1-34.el7.x86_64`, compared with the package you need, `libkadm5-1.15.1-37.el7_6`, you will see the conflicting package has an extra `.1` in the version which could be throwing off YUM's update algorithms (i.e. YUM could not determine that `libkadm5-1.15.1-37.el7_6` was a higher version then `libkadm5-1.15.1.1-34.el7.x86_64` due that that `.1`, and so it was not selected for update).  If this is the case, you may have to resolve the issue manually by removing `libkadm5-1.15.1.1-34.el7.x86_64` and replacing with `libkadm5-1.15.1-37.el7_6`.